# Java 8: Elegant way to check that two or more variables are not null

Tags: java-8, option-type

How can be done in Java 8?

```
if (var1 != null && var2!=null) {
     callMethod(var1,var2);
}
```

I was thinking with something like this but with 2 variables:

```
Optional.ofNullable(var1).ifPresent(var1 -> callMethod(var1));
```

Comment: `if(Stream.of(var1,var2, ...).noneMatch(Objects::isNull)){ ... }`

Answer (score 7):

Your example is clean and readable, there is no point in searching for alternatives. As you have mentioned, Optional can wrap a single value only.

If you want to replace multiple nonNull checks, you can create a structure

```
Stream.of(var1, var2, var3, ...).allMatch(Objects::nonNull)
```

This could be wrapped into a helper method:

```
 boolean nonNull(Object arg){
   return arg!=null;
 }
 boolean nonNull(Object arg1, Object arg2){
   return arg1!=null && arg2 !=null;
 }
 ...
 boolean nonNull(Object... args){
   return Arrays.stream(args).allMatch(Objects::nonNull);
 }
```

But for less than 3 argument's this has no point and is worse in performance.

> Keep code readable, not fancy. Short is good, shorter even better.

Comment: You could overload the method with specialized small-number-of-arguments versions, e.g. `boolean nonNull(Object arg1, Object arg2) { return arg1 != null && arg2 != null; }`, but still, it’s not much useful compared to a simple `if` statement at the use site.

Comment: True, just like in Java 9 with List, Set, Map factory methods. I was thinking about this also.